# Prompt to trigger only once and store value if page is refreshed / reloaded

Tags: javascript

I have a prompt on my page asking for the user's age. If over 18, the user is allowed on the homepage, if not, they are redirected on another website.

Problem is if I go onto another page and then come back on the homepage, the prompt triggers again, asking for the user's age again.

Is there any way to store the value entered the first time and to prevent the prompt to trigger again?

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```js
   var ageCheck = prompt("How old are you?")
    if (ageCheck >= 18) {
        alert("Welcome to Ginspiration!");
    }
    else {
      alert("You must be at least 18 years old to be allowed on this website. You will be redirected.")
        window.location.href="https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/advice/underage-drinking";
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to save answer somewhere. SESSION/COOKIE/localStorage (depends how long you want to remember it, if it should be across PC/browsers for registered users, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to store your data using `localStorage`. Which will store your data directly into your browser.

For exemple:

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Mimi');

console.log(localStorage.getItem('myCat'));
```

If I get your code it would look like this :

```
// Get the age from local storage
 const ageCheck = localStorage.getItem("age");
 
 if(!ageCheck){
  // If ageCheck is null then we prompt "How old are you?" and set the item
   const age = prompt("How old are you?")
   localStorage.setItem("age", age);
 } else {
  // Else we check the age 
  if (ageCheck >= 18) {
        alert("Welcome to Ginspiration!");
    }
    else {
      alert("You must be at least 18 years old to be allowed on this website. You will be redirected.")
        window.location.href="https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/advice/underage-drinking";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works however I'm now having the issue that the alert will trigger every time I come back on the homepage (i.e. the prompt doesn't but the alert does. I would want both not to trigger after user inputs their age).

Comment: Hi @LauraCabTay glad that I helped you. Please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If you have another problem feel free to make another post :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store value in `localstorage` and retrieve the data when page loads

```js
const data = localstorage.getItem("is18");

// Check Some Condition Here before prompting them
if (data === false) {

  var ageCheck = prompt("How old are you?")
  if (ageCheck >= 18) {
    localstorage.setItem("is18", true);
    alert("Welcome to Ginspiration!");
  } else {
    localstorage.setItem("is18", false);
    alert("You must be at least 18 years old to be allowed on this website. You will be redirected.")
    window.location.href = "https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/advice/underage-drinking";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything (the prompt doesn't trigger)